# Increasing max_parallel_downloads is not effective in yum commands

Tags: rhel, yum, parallelism

To install all the updates in a Red Hat or CentOS machine, we use the following command

```
yum -y update --skip-broken --nobest
```

We are looking for ways to improve total running time of installing the updates.
As per the yum document [yum.conf(5) - Linux manual page (man7.org)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/yum.conf.5.html), there is a parameter `max_parallel_downloads` which can be used to configure number of simultaneous packages downloads. I updated this parameter and did testing but looks like this parameter is either not getting applied or is not effective.

Following is the observations. There are 205 updates installed in a machine.

Is the parameter `max_parallel_downloads` not getting applied or is it not effective?

EC2 Instance type: t2.medium,
Clock Speed: 2.3 GHz,
HDD storage
[image]

EC2 Instance type: c5a.large,
Clock Speed: 3.3 GHz,
SSD storage,
Network Speed: 10 Gigabit/s
[image]

Comment: What is the maximum download speed allowed on your link? 40 MB/s is about 320 Mbit/s. Trying to fit further parallel downloads will not magically make the network _faster_.

Comment: The behavior is similar when used machine with higher network bandwidth but similar results. Updated the question with this detail.

Comment: Then I still think you may be _possibly_ hitting maximum throughput with the default settings (I rarely if ever get 1 Gbit/s on my 1Gbit/s network). How do the transfer speeds that you get with `yum` compare with what you get with e.g. https://www.speedtest.net or by using `scp` or `rsync` over the same networks?

Comment: The output of yum commands display the speed. I did not used any tool to check the speed.

Comment: And that's what I suggest you do, to have something to _compare_ the `yum` speeds with.

Comment: In my experience the main bottleneck related to installing a long list of packages is not the download speed through the network of the package files, but the fact that packages are installed one at a time.

When I tried to reduce the length of time between first launching a server and when the server is ready to serve traffic, the biggest reduction in time I found was to start with an image of the OS that had most of the packages already installed.  The fewer packages I needed to add for a server, the sooner it was ready to be used.  See if you can pre-build your OS images like this.